# How make UICollectionview appearing at specific section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

My problem is that I couldn't find the way to appear specific section of UICollectionview.

For example, 5 sections exsisted and I want to make 3rd section appearing at the beginning.

But 1st section only appeared and could not find the method to choose the section I want to show.

If anyone knows the way to solve this problem, please tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to modify your datamodel to order sections, and show '3rd section' as '1st section', then you can use

[scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/scrollToItemAtIndexPath%3aatScrollPosition%3aanimated%3a) on UICollectionView.

You can pass `[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:2]` assuming you have items in that section.

Comment: Thanks, It's solved. The code you suggested added on (void)viewWillAlyoutSubViews. It works.